# Paypal PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR

Tags: paypal

I am implementing paypal , my code works in sandbox , but does not work on live production .

I use

```
com.paypal.sdk : paypal android -sdk - : 2.14.1
```

Logcat

```
E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:422,exception:Unprocessable Entity

E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:{"name":"PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR","debug_id":"ca78bf1438119","message":"checkout-session not created","information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR"}

E/paypal.sdk: PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

That error usually has to do with the funding source that's being chosen for the payment.  If you believe that everything is good with that, then I'd recommend you contact PayPal Customer Support so that they can take a look to see what may be causing it.  You can reach them by clicking the Contact Us link at the bottom of a PayPal page.  This isn't an issue with the SDK or your code.